# Does PostgreSQL version 10 support pgRouting version 2.6?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, postgresql-10, pgrouting

I installed pgRouting version 2.6 through brew and I have PostgreSQL version 10.4. Now I have question: does this PostgreSQL version support pgRouting extension or not? Because every time I query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shortest_path('SELECT gid AS id, start_id::int4 AS source, end_id::int4 AS target, cost_length::float8 AS cost FROM network', 1, 135, false, false);
```

This query fails and give error message:

```
ERROR:  function shortest_path(unknown, integer, integer, boolean, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Query failed
```

Comment: So did you install pgRouting by running `create extension pgrouting` as documented [in the manual](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgRouting-installation.html#enabling-and-upgrading-in-the-database)

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name . In database i query CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting and was created, giving message EXTENSION CREATED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is outdated and removed from the core since version 2.0; you want to use one of the [current collection](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/routingFunctions.html#routing-functions) of routing functions, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM pgr_Dijkstra(
       'SELECT gid AS id,
               start_id::int4 AS source,
               end_id::int4 AS target,
               cost_length::float8 AS cost
        FROM network',
       1,
       135,
       false
     );
```